# Can I pass to Canada with a US Tourist Visa?

Tags: visas, canada, international-travel, tourist-visas

I have a American tourist visa and want to travel to Canada.

Comment: Whether you can enter a country or not depends primarily on your nationality, not what visas other countries may have granted you. Canada is a sovereign county, and is not going to grant you admission to Canada on the basis of the US granting you admission to the US.

Comment: @choster but Canada *does* grant visa exemptions to some people on the basis of their US immigration documents.  Having a US nonimmigrant visa does not trigger the Canadian visa exemption, however.

Comment: @David someone with a US green card is exempt from Canada's visitor visa requirement regardless of nationality.

Comment: @phoog Thanks, I should have mentioned that exception. choster's comment is better, so I'll delete mine. And the actual Answer (below) is better still.

Answer (score 4):

Having a visa for the US does not allow you to enter Canada. You can find out if you need a visa for Canada here http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp